# Animation is not working in view-more functionality?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a view-more functionality using css only but I am having animation only one-way. I am unable to understand what is the error in this. I am trying in this way. Please do help.

```
<div class="about-card">
     <h3>About The Golden Crest</h3>
     <p class="about-card-content show-less">Nestled in the serene surroundings and in the heart of Gangtok, Sikkim, The Golden Crest is perfect for you to spend your vacation. Giving you an ideal space to take a break from the busy schedules of life
     Nestled in the serene surroundings and in the heart of Gangtok, Sikkim, The Golden Crest is perfect for you to spend your vacation. Giving you an ideal space to take a break from the busy schedules of life
     </p>
     <a href="#" class=""> + more</a>
</div>
```

scss is :

```
.about-card {
    width:500px;
    &-content{
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      transition: all .45s cubic-bezier(.44,.99,.48,1);
      max-height: 300px;
      &.show-less{
         display: -webkit-box; 
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 38px;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating the "about-card" part of the class name, I would go for a `content` class :

```
<p class="content show-less">
```

and then referencing it with :

```
.about-card {
width:500px;
& .content{
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  transition: all .45s cubic-bezier(.44,.99,.48,1);
  ...
```

See here the JSFiddle I made : https://jsfiddle.net/8befj9t3/

Comment: Still animation comes only when I remove the show-less class.. I need animation  in both situations,  when I add the show-more class and remove the show-more class.

Comment: Ok my bad, the only way to get the animation on both sides is to remove the `display: webkit-box;` on `show-less`, and play with adding and removing this class. But then, you lose the `...` at the end of your text...maybe you can try another method to add these ?